# Rendering Bugs IE11 in Windows 7

Tags: svg, windows-7, jqgrid, scroll, internet-explorer-11

I have had several problems with rendering documents with images in IE11 and Windows 7. Swtiching browsers is not an option for me.

1. If I try to use some openlayers tools, the IE11 freezes.
2. If I put `altRows=true` in a JQGrid, scrolling won't work properly. I guess this is due to the different background images in each row of the grid.

The problems disappear if:

1. I use the same version of browser in windows 8 or higher.
2. I use older versions of IE or if I use IE 11 in compatibility mode.

I have tried to execute IE without add-ons, as well as disabling the rendering by gpu. Moreover, I have tried to executing the pages in several clients as well as the hosting in differents versions of IIS - but the problems always appear in the same cases.

Comment: any news from this bug?