# AngularJS, IE11 and mouse events

Tags: angularjs, svg, internet-explorer-11

If we using our Angular-App in Internet Explorer 11, then we observe sometimes following strange behaviour by using filters:

- No mouse clicks are possible anymore (only in address bar)
- But it's possible to move mouse and cursor change on moving in or out to clickable elements
- Also keyboard event seem to work, we can navigate through the page with tabs, Ctrl+A and F5 are possible
- We don't see any errors in console

We can't reproduce this behaviour in other browsers.

Did anyone have same problems?

Or do you have any ideas how to analyse this problem?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE:**

It's kind of demo:

1. Go first to http://www.iteraplan.de/iteraplan_ee_release/ and log in. The credentials are already there
2. Go then to http://www.iteraplan.de/app-vip-trial/#/diagram
3. Do right click on red elements and select from context menu "Show with enumertion properties" => "typeOfStatus" => "Planned"
4. Do right click on red elements and select from context menu "Show with enumertion properties" => "State of health" => "Good"
5. Do right click again and select from context menu "Coloring by numeric properties" => "Show strategic values as color (from dark to light)"

[image]

It should look like this. Click now on 1, 2 and 3 (see picture). If all three filters were possible to remove, repeat the steps 3-5 again.

**UPDATE2**

Maybe it's a SVG and IE11 bug (see [Rendering Bugs IE11 in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27062978/408780))

Comment: Where's the demo that replicates the issue?

Comment: @charlietfl unfortunately it's not easy to give a demo. We'll try to prepare an test instance

Comment: @charlietfl I've update the description by adding demo